# LibGDX returning black pixels ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

This is happening only on one device (so far reported) and can't be sure how isolated it is other than no other users have yelled at me over it.

*Huawei P9 Lite (2017) is producing this issue (https://www.pdevice.com/product/huawei-p9-lite-2017-price-specs)*

I'm simply retrieving the screen's pixels and putting them into a Pixmap. For this one device, however, the pixels (RGBA) are all [0,0,0,1] - so it's not even an alpha problem.

For all of my own test devices, and so far for all other users, this isn't happening.

```
screenPixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
ByteBuffer pixels = screenPixmap.getPixels();
Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL20.GL_RGBA, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

I feel like it has to be a GPU issue because it's kind of weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like it's just an OpenGL gotcha from what I can tell.

You can't reliably glReadPixels from the screen/default framebuffer, some cases will throw GLError 1286 aka framebuffer is bad. Most cases seems it's fine.

Luckily in my case, I'm already rendering my app to a secondary buffer before displaying that on the screen, so I'm just glReadPixels-ing that instead, seems to work now.